# Use of database for multiple Places in windows application in c#

Tags: c#, database, synchronization

I have a developed a application that is gonna to be used at multiple places.
So how should i maintain one database for all?

Or is there only one way of using remote database for this software.

If i use remote database, i am facing problem with loading controls in forms.

Please Suggest Solution.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what type of information you need to replicate?  Is it user information, product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd design a system leveraging [multi-tiered architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), which often consists of:

- Front-end user interface
- A database back-end
- Middle tier/business layer that let's your web pages access the database and provides additional business logic (perhaps a web service?)

You don't give much to go on as far as details go, but it seems like you have several physical locations that need to access a single database.  So you can:

- Develop an (web or desktop) application that handles the front-end UI and the middle tier (which will access data and do other stuff)
- Develop an application that handles only front-end UI, but calls a web service that accesses a database and does other stuff.  In this case, you may have several locations with different front-end applications that consume the same centralized web service.